# Send Mailchimp Campaign to Single Email Address

Tags: mailchimp

I'm creating custom emails (many customizations) in MailChimp campaign builder. Looks like the only option to send is via a campaign, which I'd need to manually upload a list of email addresses. I honestly just want to use the builder to send a quality form email, that I customize for each recipient.

Is it possible to send an email to a specific email address without building a list, etc? This will probably be a one-time thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can send campaign to single email address in mailchimp through this method. However you can't send the same campaign more than once to same email address.

create an automation email with **API 3.0** as trigger.

[image]

Now, to send a campaign, make POST call to the given url with email address in your mailchimp

```
https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/********/emails/********/queue
```

[image]

Now, To call that api you need to add `HTTP BAsic Auth` or `OAuth 2` to API Request. See this answer [MailChimp 3.0 HTTP POST Json Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659401/mailchimp-3-0-http-post-json-example/61095402#61095402)

There's also a npm module to make life easier https://npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-v3

---

This is just a workaround as mailchimp was not built for single emails. In the longer run I'd suggest you to look into mandrill, sendgrid or other transactional email tool.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using Mandrill, MailChimp's transactional email app, to send one off emails. You can still use or at least make use of MailChimp campaigns but you can send one off emails that are customised and you do not need to send to a list