# MailChimp 3.0 HTTP POST Json Example

Tags: java, json, http, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to make use of MailChimp's Automation trigger that activates when a subscriber's email ID is posted to an API endpoint:

[image]
([link](https://mailchimp.com/help/all-the-automation-triggers/))

Following the Workflow instructions, I'm using the following https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/xxxxxxxxxx/emails/xxxxxxxxxx/queue URL provided via the Campaign.

I can successfully send an authenticated HTTP POST request ([using this do_Post() method copied into my codebase](https://github.com/alexanderwe/bananaj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/alexanderwe/bananaj/connection/Connection.java#L44)), but am faced with a [400 error](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/) with a `Content-Type: application/problem+json` response. **My JSON is incorrect and I'm not sure what the JSON should look like to trigger the above event**.

I've tried a plethora of different cracks at the JSON - my latest attempt looks like `{"unique_email_id":"e063dfcf4g"}`. Every attempt at altering the JSON data still is returning me the same error above.

I've been wondering if I possibly need to set some more headers in the POST request, but this is beyond my area of expertise.

I appreciate the help and insights.

Comment: So after much trial and error, apparently the correct JSON is {"email_address":"example@gmail.com"}. This will make the email member from the campaign's LIST now a SUBSCRIBER to the campaign. Now ... how can I make the trigger fire to send an email to this one person on demand? I thought this is what the 'Triggers an email when a subscriber's email is posted to API endpoint' would do .. but apparently not (it only will fire one time and reject the POST if the member is already a subscriber).

Comment: If you have figured it out, consider answering your own question and posting a different one for the next problem, otherwise it gets confusing quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of `HTTP Basic Auth` Postman request:

**POST URL:**

`https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations/********/emails/********/queue`
you'll get this when you create api based trigger automation campaign.

**Authorization:**

[image]

generate the `api key` from mailchimp dashboard and use that as password in postman `authorization`. put any username.

**POST Body:**

```
{"email_address":"tigerking@gmail.com"}
```

---

Read more about mailchimp API : https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/

---

there's also a npm module for this https://npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-v3